# XMLStreamReader and UnMarshalling a SOAP Message

Tags: java, xml, soap, xml-parsing

I have a problem while decoding SOAP Envelope. 
Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tns="http://c.com/partner/">
  <env:Header>c
    <tns:MessageId env:mustUnderstand="true">3</tns:MessageId>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <GetForkliftPositionResponse xmlns="http://www.c.com">
      <ForkliftId>PC006</ForkliftId>
     </GetForkliftPositionResponse>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I use the following code to decode the body, but it always return to the namespace tns:MessageID, not to the env:body. I also would like to convert the XMLStreamReader to string for debugging issues, is it possible?

```
   XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        xif.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing", true);  // decode entities into one string

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(Message);
        String SoapBody = "";
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader( reader );
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to header tag
        xsr.nextTag(); // advance to envelope
        xsr.nextTag(); // advance to body
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially the xsr is pointing to before the document event (i.e. the XML declaration), and `nextTag()` advances to the next *tag*, not the next sibling *element*:

```
    xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to opening envelope tag
    xsr.nextTag(); // advance to opening header tag
    xsr.nextTag(); // advance to opening MessageId
```

If you want to skip to the body a better idiom would be

```
boolean foundBody = false;
while(!foundBody && xsr.hasNext()) {
  if(xsr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT &&
     "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope".equals(xsr.getNamespaceURI()) &&
     "Body".equals(xsr.getLocalName())) {
    foundBody = true;
  }
}

// if foundBody == true, then xsr is now pointing to the opening Body tag.
// if foundBody == false, then we ran out of document before finding a Body

if(foundBody) {
  // advance to the next tag - this will either be the opening tag of the
  // element inside the body, if there is one, or the closing Body tag if
  // there isn't
  if(xsr.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
    // now pointing at the opening tag of GetForkliftPositionResponse
  } else {
    // now pointing at </env:Body> - body was empty
  }
}
```

Comment: I get that exceptions 
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 3; unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", local:"Body").

I want to read what is "after" the body, so that I can unmarshell it

Comment: @AhmedSaleh once you have found the opening `Body` tag _then_ you can use `xsr.nextTag()` once in order to advance to the opening tag of the element within the body, and start unmarshalling from there.

Answer (score 1):

After xsr.nextTag() read QName, from there you can get tag name and prefix

```
QName qname = xsr.getName();
String pref = qname.getPrefix();
String name = qname.getLocalPart();
```